# Interpolating point on each line from vertex in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, geometry-generator, interpolation

How can I interpolate a point on each line from the vertex? I need to interpolate each vertex along the line for a certain distance. I need offset on all lines.

Standard QGIS tools shift incorrectly and the direction is lost. I think that the problem can only be solved using the geometry generator, function `line_interpolate_point()`.

[image]

How can I generate interpolation across all lines?

[image]

I want to get these lines with arrows.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  When I first read it I assumed that you want to create an output point layer, with points located at each input vertex.  But then you use the word offset.  Please edit your question to include an image showing what the output should look like.

Comment: Taras, thank you. 
What does "clip"?
I made a buffer and intersection. How can I get arrows on both sides?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume there is a polyline layer `"line"`, see image below.

[image: input]

---

A solution using **"Geometry Generator"** without [`line_interpolate_point()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html?highlight=line_interpolate_point).

Proceed with `RMT > Symbology > Single Symbol > Line > Geometry Generator`

[image: input1]

Apply the following settings for the arrows at lines beginnings

[image: Arrows_start]

And these settings for the arrows at lines endings

[image: Arrow_end]

The final result will look like:

[image: result]

*Note:* Arrows at starts or endings can have the same visualization settings, e.g. the same colour. In the above example I made arrows slightly distinguishable.

To maintain the original geometry of lines simply duplicate them and put under the arrows or alternatively add a `'Simple Line'` layer in the Geometry Generator, see image below.

[image: result_2]

To be capable of having an offset at the line starting or ending point, apply the following expressions

`difference(intersection($geometry, buffer(start_point($geometry), 2.5)), buffer(start_point($geometry), 0.5))`
 for a start point

or

`difference(intersection($geometry, buffer(end_point($geometry), 2.5)), buffer(end_point($geometry), 0.5))`
for an end point respectively, see image below.

[image: offset]

[image: arrows with offset]

---

A solution using **"Geometry Generator"** with [`line_interpolate_point()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html?highlight=line_interpolate_point).

[image: input2]

Settings for a staring point
`make_line(start_point($geometry), line_interpolate_point($geometry, 2))`

[image: settings_start]

Settings for an ending point
`make_line(end_point($geometry), line_interpolate_point(reverse($geometry), 2))`

[image: settings_end]

And get the result:

[image: result2]

If the line has to have an offset then apply the following expressions:
 `make_line(line_interpolate_point($geometry, 1), line_interpolate_point($geometry, 2))`
where line starts

and respectively

`make_line(line_interpolate_point(reverse($geometry), 1), line_interpolate_point(reverse($geometry), 2))`
where line ends.

The graphical output will look as follows

[image: offset2]

Afterward you will be able to create arrows over that lines.

---

**References:**

- [QGIS Docs > 14.2.2.12. Geometry Functions > line_interpolate_point](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html?highlight=line_interpolate_point)